# vlookup vba code autofill not working

Tags: vba, excel

Vlookup code filling same value. How to get right values

Source is

```
ADSU01A 15.14166667
ADSU01B 13.41944444
ADSU01C 12.21111111
ADSU01D 8.64
```

Vlookup value showing

```
ADSU01A 15.14166667
ADSU01B 15.14166667
ADSU01C 15.14166667
ADSU01D 15.14166667
```

Code used is:

```
lastrow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set Mytable = Range("A:G")

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Cells(i, 12) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), _
                   Range("Mytable"), 3, False)
Next i
```

Comment: Please do not change the edit unless you want to enhance the formatting or add any useful info.

Comment: Can I see screenshot of your source data?

Comment: Portal not letting me post images

Comment: Load it on any file uploding site and share the link here. One of us will upload it for you :)

Comment: are you sure that `Range("Mytable")` covers entire range where your data is? Shouldn't you use 2nd column in formula?

Comment: Hello, i managed to run your code without any problem with some minor corrections. Instead of `Range("Mytable")` , i used onlt `Mytable` since it is already identified as range, then i replaced 3 with 2 in `Cells(i, 12) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), Range("Mytable"), 3, False)` since it was like that in my sheet. Then code worked just fine.

Comment: Image linkhttp://expirebox.com/download/da494fa2e66f00025afe7c2d0893ae17.html

Comment: @Dubison..Please check in your sheet, if you put the values of A column, into K column in jumbled sequence...and then take K column as reference..then run code

Comment: yes it works perfectly. All i need to do is to change the `VLookup(ws.Cells(i, 1)` to `VLookup(ws.Cells(i, 11)` where 11 refering the column K. I have updated the code below accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code worked fine for me with the layout in the image.

[image]

```
Sub vlookupadd()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet


lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set mytable = ws.Range("A:G")

For i = 2 To lastrow
    ws.Cells(i, 12) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Cells(i, 11), mytable, 2, False)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: When i changed as suggested, (i,1) replace by (i,11), I am getting error "Unable to get vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class" , Trying to debug

Comment: Hi Abhas, can you please have a look at this topic. They were discussing the same condition. It is mentioned that error may cause because the data you are looking for is not in your list. [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280477/unable-to-get-the-vlookup-property-of-the-worksheetfunction-class-error)