# convert vlookup function to VBA this code in excel

Tags: vba, vlookup

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L19,DB,2,0),"")
```

need to convert this function to VBA in excel

Comment: at what cell do you want it this formula converted ? the active cell ?   The second parameter inside your VLookup is `DB` , is that an error ? or a Named Range ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280477/unable-to-get-the-vlookup-property-of-the-worksheetfunction-class-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the result of the formula in cell A19 (for example only), and **DB** is a named Range, try using the following code

```
Sub IsError_VLookup()

    If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("L19"), Range("DB"), 2, 0)) Then
        Range("A19").Value = ""
    Else
        Range("A19").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("L19"), Range("DB"), 2, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```