# VBA - VLookup function not woking

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone tell me why is this not working? This stop working my macro and an error message appears

```
Sh.Cells(2, 13).Formula = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sh.Cells(2, 6) & " - " & Sh.Cells(2, 8), Worksheets("Licenciaturas").Range("H2:K2928"), 4, False)
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19280477/3709765)?!

Comment: since you are using the WorksheetFunction of VLookup, you don't need the ".Formula" , you can just use 'Sh.Cells(2, 13) = ....'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to add it as a formula to the cell, or just return the result of the VLookup and place that in the cell?

Your code looks like it's trying to do a bit of both.

If you want a formula to appear in your sheet use:

```
Sh.Cells(2, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R2C6 & "" - "" & R2C8, 'Licenciaturas'!R2C8:R2928C8,4,FALSE)"
```

The formula will appear as: `=VLOOKUP($F$2 & " - " & $H$2, Licenciaturas!$H$2:$H$2928,4,FALSE)`