# VLookUp not working - Property could not be assigned

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

My problem is, that when using the VlookUp I do get the Error:

**The VLookup-Property of the WorksheetFunction-Object could not be assigned**

```
        ' LookUp missing Data
        Dim lookupRange As Range
        Set lookupRange = Sheets("Kundenlisten HLK 2018").Range("A1:Y10354")

        ' Fill in Companyname
        Dim tmp As String
        tmp = Values(0)
        tmp = TrueTrim(tmp)
        testing.Cells(8, counter) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tmp, lookupWS.Range("A2:Y10354"), 2, False)

        Values = None
        counter = counter + 1
```

**lookupWS** is the Name of the Worksheet 
As you can see the table I am trying to lookup is filled with values from A to Y. The first column is the key I am trying to look up, but then the error from above occurs. The **tmp** variable is a String with a unique ID to look up the missing values, while the "2" is supposed to be the company name in the second column of the Range.

I looked up on the docs, but the types and everything are fine, I even checked while debugging.

**testing.Cells(8, counter)** can't be the source of the problem aswell, since I am using it before like this

```
testing.Cells(28, counter) = Left(mail.ReceivedTime, 10)
```

and it works

Comment: What is `lookupWS`? Was that supposed to be `lookupRange`? You declare a variable that you don't use but then use a variable that you don't declare. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Does the lookup value exist? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280477/unable-to-get-the-vlookup-property-of-the-worksheetfunction-class-error

Comment: Without any *data* we really can't help you

Comment: @John Coleman lookupRange is defined in the code, you are right lookupWS isnt, my fault. Ist is the worksheet

Comment: @QHarr omg you were right! I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I am on PC again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to know what the problem is without any data, but here's something to help you in the right direction.

> It's better to use `Find` and `Offset` than
>   `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` in VBA

Something like this gives you exactly the same result, but you have much more control:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim valueFound As Range

    Set valueFound = lookupWS.Range("A2:A10354").Find(What:="Something", lookat:=xlWhole) 'xlWhole is equivalent to FALSE in VLOOKUP
    If valueFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    Else
        MsgBox valueFound.Offset(0, 1) 'offsetting by 1 is equivalent to using 2 in a VLOOKUP
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That is so much better and gives better Feedback on errors