# Excel UserForm to track employees returning to office for work not limiting total number according to indicated limit

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

Background: So with all the work from home measures due to the pandemic, my company decided to let employees choose the day they want to return to office each week, on a first come first serve basis, while limiting the total number of employees in office each day to 50% of all employees. There are also some exceptions, like some of the higher ups will have fixed days in office, which means the available "slots" each day differs. While looking for an efficient automated way to track the number of employees returning to office, I chanced upon UserForm in VBA (this is my first time using VBA).

Main Point: So I managed to come up with an UserForm where employees enter their name and choose the date they want to return and click a CommandButton to add the data to the list. **But I'm encountering problems with the part of "limiting total number of employees in office each day to 50%"**. Following is the code I'm trying for the CommandButton:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
 
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lDate As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("MainData")

'Find first empty row in database
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

lDate = Me.cbxDate.ListIndex

'Check for inputs
If Trim(Me.txtName.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtName.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter name"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.cbxDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cbxDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please choose a date"
  Exit Sub
End If

'Check if chosen date has hit 50% capacity (as indicated in LookupLists Limit column)
Dim x As Double
x = Me.cbxDate.Value

CountDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("MainDate"), "= Me.cbxDate.Value")
Ret = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookUp(x, Worksheets("LookupLists").Range("DateLimit"),2,False)

If CountDate > Ret Then
  Me.cbxDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Date chosen has hit 50%. Please choose another date"
  Me.cbxDate.Value = ""
End If
    
'Copying the data to the database
With ws
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cbxDate.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cbxDate.List(lDate, 1)
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtName.Value
End With

Unload Me
 
End Sub
```

EDIT: So I previously encountered the error 1004: Unable to get VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class. But I edited the code and I don't get the error anymore. However, I'm still unable to get the MsgBox asking user to choose another date to appear even though there's already (I wrote 15 in the limit column of my LookupLists) 15 entries on 1/4/21. How do I fix this?

Also is there a better way to check if the date chosen has reached the limit? Is there also a way to remove a certain date from the userform combobox once the limit for the day is reached? (so user can't choose that date anymore)

Thanks!

Comment: The code in question doesn't throw an error because it doesn't compile. Vlookup code is probably based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19280559) - the same meaningless variable name. This answer explains when it throws an error and how to deal with it.

Comment: @BrakNicku I edited the code according to the link you mentioned and I don't get the error anymore. But I still can't get the msgbox to appear even though the number of entries with a certain date (say 1/4/21) has reached the limit I wrote in my LookupLists worksheet...

Comment: If you want to increase your chances of getting help, there is one major rule: never post fake code. And the code in post is most definitely fake, because at least 3 lines won't compile. The one with VLookup should have `x` instead of `x.value`, the CountIf line is missing a quote character, the second parameter should be `"=" & x`.

Comment: @BrakNicku omg okay yes changing the CountIf line to "=" & x worked! I think cause it still ran even though it was written "= Me.cbxDate.Value" so I thought there wasn't any problems with that line. But the msgbox pops up once the limit is reached now! Just needa go try this on my work laptop. Thanks!

Comment: If you had `"= Me.cbxDate.Value"` - it was counting cells with " Me.cbxDate.Value" literal text. To count cells with the value of combobox you should use `"=" & Me.cbxDate.Value`.  `Value` property of combobox is Variant, using intermediate variable `x` forces its conversion to Double, so using `CDbl(Me.cbxDate.Value)` should work as well.